# FFMPEG - mergedVideo two video getting error

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg

I have created a video with images and audio successfully but i am mergedVideo getting error Error ffmpeg exited with code 1: Cannot find a matching stream for unlabeled input pad 3 on filter Parsed_concat_0 –

```
    var mergedVideo = ffmpeg();
    var videoNames = [finalVideoPath,__dirname + "/video/video.mp4"];

    videoNames.forEach(function(videoName){
        mergedVideo = mergedVideo.addInput(videoName);
    });

    mergedVideo.mergeToFile(margeVideoPath)
    .on('error', function(err) {
        console.log('Error ' + err.message);
    })

    .on('end', function() {
        console.log('Finished!');
    });
```

Comment: Please include the code you've written   in  your question.

Comment: I have created a video with images and audio successfully but i am mergedVideo getting error Error ffmpeg exited with code 1: Cannot find a matching stream for unlabeled input pad 3 on filter Parsed_concat_0